# Is there a way to match calendar colors without MobileMe?

Tags: iphone, data-synchronization, ical, google-calendar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I change the colors of calendars on iOS5](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/27747/how-can-i-change-the-colors-of-calendars-on-ios5)

I have an iPhone 4 that syncs with iCal through Google. However, the colors for the calendars are different on the iPhone than on iCal. Is there any way to set the colors for the calendars on the iPhone so that they are the same as the colors I have selected in iCal?

Comment: Normally we merge down to the oldest questions - but since iOS has fixed this, we will likely close this and the question it is a duplicate and keep them as historical reference and not something needed on iOS 6 or later as we go into 2013.

Comment: Keep in mind not all iOS devices are running iOS 6. It's not just for historic reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no official way to achieve this, however you can try [a trick involving deactivating / reactivating calendars](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google%20Mobile/thread?tid=3d8377b8eb791bfc&hl=en) in a certain order until they match the colour you want.

Comment: Not a great solution, but it seems there is no better option.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have your preferred colors set in iCal, try this on your next sync:

**BE SURE YOU SYNC ANY CALENDAR INFO YOU MIGHT HAVE ADDED VIA THE PHONE *BEFORE* DOING THIS OVERWRITE**

1. In iTunes, select your iPhone in "Devices" (same as normal sync)
2. At the top of the sync window, click on "Info"
3. Scroll down to the Advanced heading
4. Under "Replace information on this iPhone", check the "Calendars" box
5. Sync at will

This should override all of the calendar settings on your iPhone, and replace them with the settings from iCal.