# How can I change the colors of calendars on iOS5

Tags: ios, google-calendar

Supposedly, you can change the colors of calendars from the iPhone now. How!? (In particular, I'm trying to do it for google calendars synced via exchange, but I can't see how to do it with iCloud ones, either.)

Comment: As a historical note - on iOS 4 - it was very hard to manage the colors of multiple calendars on multiple devices. On iOS 5 it got better since you could change things by hand. I haven't heard of it being an issue on iOS 6.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this in the Calendar app.

1) Tap **Calendars** in the upper left corner:

[image: Calendars button]

2) Then tap **Edit**:

[image: Edit button]

3) Select the calendar you want to change the colour of:

[image: Calendar selection]

4) Pick the colour you want. If you want a more extensive selection than what's in the list, you need to do it from iCal on your Mac.

[image: Colour picker]

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but this only works with iCloud calendars... Google calendar colors cannot be changed this way...

Comment: I am not sure why this did not work for @endelight (so this may not apply to them), but I have two Google Calendars. One was added manually, the other via a profile (by the iPhone Configuration Utility from Apple).  The one that I added manually, I can change the color on, the one that was done via the profile I can't. I am guessing because it is in a profile, it is locked down.

Comment: @JimJan same problem here