# How to change color of Birthdays calendar?

Tags: macos, ios, icloud, calendar, color

I'm surprised this doesn't appear to have been asked here. Trying to change the color of the "Birthdays" calendar generated from my Apple Contacts and shared via iCloud to my macOS and iOS devices.

On iOS (10.2.1), it's an undesirable green. On macOS (10.12.3) and in iCloud's web app (https://www.icloud.com/#calendar), it's a nice, neutral grey.

On iOS, all calendars *except* "Birthdays" have the "(i)" icon at the right-side end of their entry to open a menu that includes setting of display color.

I've tried control-clicking and hold-tapping, I've toggled on/off, I've dug through the three versions of the app and through each device's settings.

Thank you.

Comment: Same as it's been since iOS 5, though the positioning has changed slightly, it's still intelligible from - http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/27747/how-can-i-change-the-colors-of-calendars-on-ios5?rq=1

Comment: All calendars except "Birthdays" have the "(i)" button to change their colors in the iOS Calendars app.

Comment: hmm... you're right. I have that one switched off, so never noticed. I have mine in a regular shared calendar, the system one is far too irritating ;)